# Adding products to category in Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento, categories, product

is there a way of selecting, which products are in which category via category management?

I have like 1000 products and 10 categories. So far, I have to go to every product and tick where it belongs.

I would like to do it other way - select category and tick which products belong there. Would be much more painful :) Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the aynber instruction you go to Catalog -> Manage Categories and on Left column you click on your category, once category is selected you go to Product tab on right side of screen.

There you got all products on this category, on the first column on header you got combo box with Yes / No / Both.

Select Both, and press Filter.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done under Catalog -> Manage Categories. Select the category, then click on Category Products.

Comment: But how? When I do this and choose category which I want to fill with products, the list of all products disappear, because the category is empty...

Comment: Change "Yes" to "No" or "Any" and click on Search to pull up the full list. You can also search for certain products at the top of that table.